# What can be causing the problem that I can't make a screenshot from my iPhone app in the Organizer window?

Tags: iphone, xcode, screenshot

For some reason, when I press "Capture" while my device is connected and running the app (launched via Build & Run in Xcode), nothing happens. Never get a screenshot. iPhone OS 3.0. What can be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem—it seems to be caused by there being a screenshot currently selected in the Organizer. Click on the left-hand screenshot pane to highlight it (i.e. deselect whatever screenshot thumbnail is selected), then hit the Capture button.